# UserControl display order in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I have a main `Window` and several `UserControls`, that show in the same position (one on the other).

How can I adjust the newly opened `UserControl` to appear at the very top?

With what I have now, if one of them is opened, and another is opening, the new one goes to the bottom.

Comment: Please show some code/XAML. `Window` only accepts one child, so there is certainly some other container in the mix. I expect that it is a `Grid`, but we need to understand what these user controls are and what it means to be "opening" new ones.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, what do you want to adjust ? what do you mean when you talk about an "open usercontrol" ?

Comment: Yes, it's Grid. And open = show. ZIndex proposed by @HCL is right thing at the right place at the right time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex.aspx)-property to set the Z-Index in supporting containers (`Canvas`). In Grid-controls, the last added element will be the topmost one (implicit `ZIndex`).

Answer (score 1):

Try `Visibility` property. Put it `Collapsed` if you want to hide it, and `Visible` to show again.

On MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(v=VS.90).aspx